# Use ESP GPIO to toggle LED

Tags: led, esp8266

How can i toggle a LED with a GPIO pin and keep the state of the switching circuit even when the ESP is in deep sleep or shut down.

I want the LED to toggle on a HIGH signal on the pin.

I found some solutions for push buttons and debouncing with inverters or d-type flip flops but i am not sure if they work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the state of the GPIO pin to EEPROM - memory onboard the ESP32 that survives a complete power outage.  You just have to be aware that there is a limited number of write cycles to each register.  If your system is restarting every minute, be careful. If you system is restarting every day, you'll be ok for many years.

Here is a how-to web page.
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-flash-memory/

If you want to keep the LEd on during deep sleep, you can add a set/reset latch like a flip/flop. You'll need tom one time a second line from flip/flop output back to a digital input on your ESP so you can check the state of the flip-flop once the esp comes out of deep sleep.

You can also try an SCR and transistor in parallel. The SCR can be triggered to stay on (left button) and stay on when button is released (or when your esp is out in deep sleep).  The transistor can be pulled high with a microcontroller input (or pressing the button) to turn off the LED...

[image]

Comment: I am using esp8266 and I do not only to preserve the state. I also want the led to be on even if esp is in deep sleep or shut down.

Comment: The esp8266 has the same eeprom features, just less storage space.

Comment: Check added comment on my answer about keeping the LED on in deep sleep.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have a circuit diagram or any suggestions for the needed component?

Comment: Search d-type flip flop like this (There are hundreds of option).  https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC1G74.pdf

Comment: Another option was added to my answer using SCR.

Comment: when I use the 74LVC1G74: what should i do with clock pin?